# Java out of memory error on CentOS

Tags: java, out-of-memory

Hi,

I am running an application that requires java on a CentOS server but it is continuously crashing. When I look at the logs this is what I get:

```
Server exception monitor uncatched exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

This is my java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Seems like it is out of memory or something but I have no idea how to fix this. What should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your application more heap memory, using the `-Xmx` flag at execution time:

```
$ java -Xmx4096m ...
```

Comment: Is that command for expanding the java memory in general or only certain application?

Comment: It is for the JVM that is created when you run your application.

Comment: So I only need to start the application and then run the command? No need to specify any other parameters?

Comment: When you start your application, you need to set the `Xmx` value to something larger than it's currently getting set to.

Comment: With other parameters I mean like paths or something. How can I know which is the current limit?

Comment: Examine how the current application is being started, and then modify it. You'll need to do some homework here - I'm not going to be walking you through it step-by-step

Comment: I know, but its just I dont have any experience with java at all but yet I must fix this problem and I dont even know where to begin from.

Comment: Well, looks like you get a chance to learn it. :) Server Fault is not a "get someone to do my work for free" site, or a site to get urgent help. Nor is it a replacement for you doing research and trying to solve the problem on your own. Many of us are available for consulting if you need urgent help.

Comment: I understand that perfectly. I dont intend to ask you to do the work. I am only asking you for a hint on where to begin from. I have been doing soem research on my own but I havent found anything close to my issue and thats why I decided to ask here to get a little more straight answer to this particular problem.

Comment: I've given you plenty of hints as to where to start. Good luck!

Comment: Usually application has system requirements. if default heap size is not enough  - it should be specified. And complete answer should advise to verify whether java process launched according to system requirements. If yes, application should be profiled - in case of resource leaks server application will crash eventually and later error can cost more expansive (data loss, etc).

Comment: @Kaponir I get it. You are upset about your questions being closed on Server Fault. Feel free to continue finding nits to pick on my answers and down voting them if it makes you feel like a better person. However, if you really want to be productive and contribute to the site, you may consider either editing my answer to improve it or writing your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you run an application via init script, you should take a look at that script to see where you can adjust memory setting for your application.

If you run an application directly by command, use the options like @EEAA said. This memory will be allocated to JVM whenever you execute the command.

and btw, which application are you trying to run?

Comment: Its called 123flashchat and its started with only one command something like: fcserver start. It doesnt require me to do anything else so I guess the application itself start the java automatically but how it does that its beyond my me.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had already found it. I tried it and now I just need to wait and see. I was just wondering if the setting had to be changed in java itself.